# Power loss in 3-port resistive splitter

Tags: power, rf

[image]

Why is the loss at ports 2 and 3 6.02 dB? I understand that the power is split evenly, so 3.01 dB is from that, but I’m struggling to prove mathematically that the resistive losses also equal 3.01 dB.

Comment: Maybe you're getting voltage and power confused?  Remember 6 dB in voltage difference is 3 dB in power.

Comment: Hi Steve, here is what I’m referring to: “Their down side is that a two-way resistive splitter suffers 10xlog(1/2) or 3.0103 dB of real resistive loss , as opposed to a lossless splitter like a hybrid. Accounting for 3.0103 dB real loss and 3.0103 dB power split, the net power transfer loss you will observe from input to one of two outputs is 6.0206 dB for a two-way resistive splitter, so they are often called 6 dB splitters“ … from https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/resistive-power-splitters